# List files in directory with bun

Tags: javascript, utilities, bun

Is it possible to list files in directory with bun?

Looked into the docs for the [bun utilities](https://bun.sh/guides/util) but can't seem to find it. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: use node api ```fs.readdir``` (provided by `fs` or `fs/promises` module)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can

```
import { Glob } from "bun";

const glob = new Glob("*");

for (const file of glob.scanSync(".")) {
    console.log(file);
}
```

More in the documentation: https://bun.sh/docs/api/glob

Answer (score 9):

As of Q3 2023, Bun does not yet provide its own fully-featured filesystem library - their documentation says to [use their reimplementation](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis#node-fs) [of NodeJS's `fs` library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

> https://bun.sh/docs/api/file-io
> [...]
> For operations that are not yet available with Bun.file, such as mkdir, you can use Bun's nearly complete implementation of the node:fs module.

Bun's reimplementation is documented at https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis#node-fs

To get a list of files in a directory with Bun, this *should* work (untested):

```
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { join } from 'node:path';

/**
 * @param {string | Buffer | URL} directoryPath
 * @returns {Promise<string[]>} - Array of long file paths
 */
async function getFiles( directoryPath ) {

    try {
        const fileNames = await readdir( directoryPath ); // returns a JS array of just short/local file-names, not paths.
        const filePaths = fileNames.map( fn => join( directoryPath, fn ) );
        return filePaths;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error( err ); // depending on your application, this `catch` block (as-is) may be inappropriate; consider instead, either not-catching and/or re-throwing a new Error with the previous err attached.
    }
}
```